# Поиск 'последовательно' идущих строк в файле с помощью grep/egrep

Tags: linux, grep

У меня есть большой json-массив. В нём у каждого элемента есть определённые поля.
Я хочу вывести ряд полей, условно `id` и `value`, где `id` из определённого списка. Список не такой большой, подразумевает, что я могу его вручную вывести. Хотя вариант, когда список в отдельном файле и каждая строка - это некоторый `id`, тоже возможен.
Кратко:

```
{
...
id: "aaa"
value: "zzz"
...
}
{
...
id: "bbb"
value: "xxx"
...
}
{
...
id: "ccc"
value: "yyy"
...
}
...
```

И я хочу вывести пару `id - value` только для `id`, к примеру содержащих `aaa` и `bbb`.

Причём необязательно, что сперва будет поле `id`, а потом `value`.

Мне кажется так вывести не получится, не написав свой скрипт. Я прав?

**UPD**: id не обязательно перед value - это "в целом" относительно структуры json. Но если (условно на сервере) политика генерации такая, что он выдаёт сперва value, а потом id, то так будет для всех json-ов, а не то, что у одного json сперва id, потом value, а следующего - наоборот.

Но при этом, скорее всего, поля id и value не будут стоять рядом друг с другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Подобрать конвертор `json2csv`
2. grep regex вроде такого: `(JPEG|JPG)`
3. (опционально) `csv2json`

Comment: Мне кажется тогда уже будет (для меня) проще написать простую тулзу на c# или java :-). Ещё такой момент, который я упустил - реально у меня винда, но большинство утилит (grep, egrep) есть.

Comment: со стандартним *nix grep'ом это точно можно сделать (понадобится еще awk). В виндах, не знаю. Делали `ifconfig | grep ...` с выводом нужных полей из разных строк.

Comment: Если id / value могут идти в произвольном порядке, боюсь придется таки использовать парсер json.

Comment: @andy.37: как насчет `grep -C1`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не уверен, что поможет если есть `{..., id: 'aaa', ..., value: bbb. ...}` так же как и `{..., value: bbb, ..., id: 'aaa', }`

Comment: Обновил первый пост для бОльшей ясности.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы точно знаете, что строки будут стоять рядом, но порядок может быть разный, то можно использовать параметр `-C[num, --context=num]` — вместе с найденной строкой взять N строк до и после. А потом еще раз фильтруем, чтобы исключить ненужные строки.

```
cat myfile.json | egrep -C1 'id: "(aaa|bbb)"' | egrep 'id:|value:'
```

Comment: не. Порядок будет всегда один и тот же, просто не обязательно, что в json будет всегда id перед value. А вот, что они будут друг за другом - скорее всего нет.